# Sturm-Liouville problem with approximated coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

Consider the problem 
$$f(x)y(x)''+\lambda y(x)=0$$
with
$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$

In many cases it is not immediate finding the analytical solution of the differential equations because it depends on the coefficient $f(x)$. In the buckling problem it is sufficient evaluating the first value of $\lambda$ (the smallest eigenvalue, namely critical load). I would substitute f(x) with another similar function g(x) such that the differential equation can be solved. The new equation will be

$$g(x)y(x)''+\hat \lambda y(x)=0$$
with
$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$

Question: Can I evaluate the maximum error among $\lambda$ and $\hat \lambda$ in terms of the relation between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: The question arises from buckling problem of slender columns with varying flexural stiffness. For engineers it is important to evaluate the buckling load of these kind of columns but it is often hard to find this value when the column presents varying flexural stiffness.